# convert string input to instance of object name(=input)

Tags: java, string, object, instanceof

I have a lot of classes and I want the user to type a name and he will get instance of the same name of a specific object (class). I simplify it by this code:

```
public class Animal {...}

public class lion extends Animal{...}
public class zebra extends Animal{...} // and so on for a lot of animals

String name = input from user
Animal something = new Animal(instance of the input name)
```

At the last line I actually wanted to convert the string name to be instance of a class name. Is there any way to do it?
there is going to be a lot of animals so i don't want to write a lot of switch cases as: "if input equals to lion" or zebra or snake or...

Comment: How's `if (name.equals("zebra")) {...} else if (name.equals("lion")) {...}` for a possibility?

Comment: your question is not clear. what you want to do excatly

Answer (score 2):

> I want the user to type a name and he will get instance of the same name of a specific object (class).

[`Class.forName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) is what you are looking for , if I'm not wrong ?

> Returns the Class object associated with the class or interface with the given string name.

```
Object obj = Class.forName(user_enterd_name).newInstance();
```

Comment: I tried that, maybe im doing something wrong but it doesnt work. Object obj = Class.forName("lion").newInstance();  the eclipse say: Multiple markers at this line
 - Unhandled exception type 
  InstantiationException
 - Unhandled exception type

Comment: That's because Class.forName().newInstance() throws multiple exceptions that need to be caught. This code is compiling for me in Eclipse:         try
        {
            Class.forName("className").newInstance();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Answer (score 1):

I suggest here to create a `Factory` class that create the suitable instance for you

For Example:

```
public class AnimalFactory {

    public Animal getAnimal(String input) {
        if(input.equals("lion")) {
            return new lion();
        } else if(input.equals("zebra")) {
            return new zebra();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go with that (it uses reflection):

```
public static Animal createAnimal(String name) {
    try {
        String package = "your.pkg"; // assuming all classes resume in the same package
        String fqn = package + "." + name;
        Class<?> animalClass = Class.forName(fqn);
        return (Animal) animalClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null; // react to any exception here
    }
}
```

This code snippet requires all animal sub classes to have a default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make `Animal` an abstract class and introduce a `AnimalFactory` which creates you the required types (this Factory may use a switch). You could as well introduce an Enum `AnimalTypes` instead of your String representation.

```
public class AnimalFactory {

    public Animal create(AnimalType animal) {
        switch (animal) {
            case lion: return new lion(); break;
            case dog: return new dog(); break;
            default: break;
        }
    }
}
```

Your 'animals' all extend the abstract class `Animal`.

Answer (score 0):

Technically this should work for you, this is just a snippet not sure if it works, if you encounter issues, add comment and I'll make it more generic

```
Map<String, Class> classes = new HashMap<>();
classes.put("zebra", Zebra.class);
classes.put("lion", Lion.class);
classes.put("etc", Etc.class);

Animal aClass = classes.get(animalName).newInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to ask is that the input name must be a class name like, if the user inputs lion then instance of lion must be created.
If this is the condition then you must use java reflection.
For example - **Class cls = Class.forName(inputUserName);**
This will get you the required class.
Now to create the instance for the class 
   **Object clsInstance = (Object) cls.newInstance();**